NavLink and Link is not navigating on Ios
I'm working a project on React Vite and added hamburger Navbar for phones but its not navigating in Iphones,
i tried on iphone 15, SE, and 8plus, but its not working on any of them and idk about its working on  MacOS or not. First i used NavLink but it was not working on iphones but then i tried using only Link for hamburger but still its not working
i tried on iphone 15, SE, and 8plus, but its not working on any of them and idk about its working on  MacOS or not. First i used NavLink but it was not working on iphones but then i tried using only Link for hamburger but still its not working
import { NavLink,Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Hamburger from 'hamburger-react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    
    const location = useLocation();


    const toggleDropdown = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsOpen(false);

    }, [location]);

    const getNavLinkClass = ({ isActive }) => isActive ? "hover:text-purple-300 text-lg font-normal text-purple-300" : "hover:text-purple-300 text-lg font-normal";

    return (
        <div data-theme="business" className="navbar  border-b border-slate-600">
            <div className="flex-1 ml-5">
             <Link to={'/'}>   <img src="https://www.payboostbills.com/static/media/pbblogo.2781af64db3db9d44aa5.png" className="w-20" alt="" />
           </Link>
              </div>
            <div className="flex-none font-bold space-x-6 mr-10 hidden sm:block">
                <NavLink className={getNavLinkClass} to={'/'}>Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink className={getNavLinkClass} to={'/about'}>About Us</NavLink>
                <NavLink className={getNavLinkClass} to={'/contact'}>Contact Us</NavLink>
                <NavLink className={getNavLinkClass} to={'/frequentlyAsked'}>FAQS</NavLink>
            </div>
            <label className="swap swap-rotate mr-5">
                <input type="checkbox"  className="theme-controller" value="night" />
                <svg className="swap-on fill-current w-10 h-10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5.64,17l-.71.71a1,1,0,0,0,0,1.41,1,1,0,0,0,1.41,0l.71-.71A1,1,0,0,0,5.64,17ZM5,12a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H3a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H4A1,1,0,0,0,5,12Zm7-7a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V3a1,1,0,0,0-2,0V4A1,1,0,0,0,12,5ZM5.64,7.05a1,1,0,0,0,.7.29,1,1,0,0,0,.71-.29,1,1,0,0,0,0-1.41l-.71-.71A1,1,0,0,0,4.93,6.34Zm12,.29a1,1,0,0,0,.7-.29l.71-.71a1,1,0,1,0-1.41-1.41L17,5.64a1,1,0,0,0,0,1.41A1,1,0,0,0,17.66,7.34ZM21,11H20a1,1,0,0,0,0,2h1a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-9,8a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v1a1,1,0,0,0,2,0V20A1,1,0,0,0,12,19ZM18.36,17A1,1,0,0,0,17,18.36l.71.71a1,1,0,0,0,1.41,0,1,1,0,0,0,0-1.41ZM12,6.5A5.5,5.5,0,1,0,17.5,12,5.51,5.51,0,0,0,12,6.5Zm0,9A3.5,3.5,0,1,1,15.5,12,3.5,3.5,0,0,1,12,15.5Z" /></svg>
                <svg className="swap-off fill-current w-10 h-10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.64,13a1,1,0,0,0-1.05-.14,8.05,8.05,0,0,1-3.37.73A8.15,8.15,0,0,1,9.08,5.49a8.59,8.59,0,0,1,.25-2A1,1,0,0,0,8,2.36,10.14,10.14,0,1,0,22,14.05,1,1,0,0,0,21.64,13Zm-9.5,6.69A8.14,8.14,0,0,1,7.08,5.22v.27A10.15,10.15,0,0,0,17.22,15.63a9.79,9.79,0,0,0,2.1-.22A8.11,8.11,0,0,1,12.14,19.73Z" /></svg>
            </label>
            <div className="dropdown relative block sm:hidden">
                <div tabIndex={0} className="m-1" onClick={toggleDropdown}>
                    <Hamburger  toggled={isOpen} toggle={setIsOpen} />
                </div>
                {isOpen && (
                    <ul className="dropdown-content z-[1] menu  p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box absolute right-0 w-52">
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to={'/'} className={getNavLinkClass}>
                                Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to={'/about'} className={getNavLinkClass}>
                                About Us
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to={'/contact'} className={getNavLinkClass}>
                                Contact Us
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to={'/frequentlyAsked'} className={getNavLinkClass}>
                                FAQS
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;


